# How can I get my reservations widget to center in row and have calendar picker appear above myslider?

Tags: css, position, z-index

I am attempting to get my reservations widget to center in a row and have the calendar picker appear above the slider (it is currently hidden below when the calendar pops up.)

I am a coding novice and am flailing with various code snippets I find but to no avail. Any help would be very much appreciated.

The page is http://lydiamountainlodge.com/cb_index.html

The reservations widget code snippet is script

```
   <script>src="https://hotels.cloudbeds.com/widget/load/t7v9Am/float?newWindow=1"></script>
```

I've added these bits of code to my css file but not getting there yet.

```
   .frame_block {
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: 960px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1000;}



    #widget-frame {
        resize: none;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1000;
        }

    .float_bg2 {
        background: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 50001;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        display: block;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 600;
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #fff;
        }
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

For the `<div>` you should set the position to relative: `position: relative;` , `justify-content: center;` , `display: flex;` , `align-items: center;` and set the `margin` untill its okay or set it to `auto` or `0`. If anything of these works, try with the `transform: translate(0%, choosen)` where you must leave 0% because it's the vertical position and instead of choosen write your own percentual.

To make you calendar appear above the slider, just cut-copy the snippet first of the slider. And after remmeber to check if all works correctly though you will have to change somethings. If there are other problems, please comment this answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the updates haven't yet fixed the problem. Any other suggestions you might have?

Comment: I personally don't have any other solution, excuse me. Try search the problem online but you might jus tried out.

Comment: Thank you again, Signor Gatto. I appreciate you taking a shot at it!

Comment: Oh don't worry, I'll study your site more accurately when I'll have time. If I find a solution, hope for a comment!